# 504 Gateway Time-out NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running a script that will require some time to run
I'm getting this error when trying to run it

```
504 Gateway Time-out - nginx
```

these are the values updated on my php.ini

```
max_input_time = 6000
max_execution_time = 60000
memory_limit = 256M
```

as i read and understand the problems resides with "FcgidIOTimeout" which i need to update on  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf"
problem is i don't have an "httpd" folder , and on /etc/appche2/conf.d/there is no fcgid.conf

I do have "fastcgi.conf" under /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf but updating FcgidIOTimeout there and restarting Apache didn't help me.

what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your nginx block

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 60000; # or whatever number you need
```

Comment: add it to which file ?

Comment: inside your location block in `nginx.conf` ... could you please provide us with your server structure? you tagged this with apache and nginx and fastcgi .. do you use all those on your server?